# removing extra white space between columns in a multi page, landscaped, longtable

Tags: tables, spacing

Hi I am trying to make a table that is landscape and takes up multiple pages.  I am using a `longtable` in landscape mode to do this.  Everything compiles fine but for some reason there is a large white space between my 3rd and 4th column. I would like to remove the white space and shift all the other columns over.  This will create some white space at the end of the table.  here is the code:

```
\begin{singlespace} 
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{cp{0.75in}p{0.75in}cccccccccc}
\caption[Photometry Source List]{Photometry for all Sources found in PID 36} \\

%This is the header for the first page of the table...
 \hline
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\#}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{p{0.75in}}{\textbf{RA}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{p{0.75in}}{\textbf{DEC}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$m_{3.6}$}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\sigma_{3.6}$}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$m_{4.5}$}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\sigma_{4.5}$}} &
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$m_{5.8}$}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\sigma_{5.8}$}} &
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$m_{8.0}$}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\sigma_{8.0}$}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\alpha_{IRAC}$}}    &
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Class}}      \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

%This is the header for the remaining page(s) of the table...
\multicolumn{3}{c}
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
  \hline
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\#}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{p{0.75in}}{\textbf{RA}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{p{0.75in}}{\textbf{DEC}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$m_{3.6}$}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\sigma_{3.6}$}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$m_{4.5}$}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\sigma_{4.5}$}} &
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$m_{5.8}$}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\sigma_{5.8}$}} &
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$m_{8.0}$}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\sigma_{8.0}$}}  &
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\alpha_{IRAC}$}}    &
                  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Class}}      \\ \hline
\endhead

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

     1&3:44:07.70&32:05:05.58&    11.77&     0.04&    11.95&     0.01&    13.01&     0.10&    11.22&     0.05&    -2.50&III\\
       2&3:44:06.16&32:07:07.08&    11.45&     0.03&    11.47&     0.01&    11.41&     0.03&    11.32&     0.05&    -2.68&III\\
       3&3:44:05.31&32:08:02.97&    12.46&     0.04&    12.62&     0.02&    12.65&     0.03&    12.18&     0.20&    -2.52&III\\
       4&3:44:04.24&32:09:38.55&    12.48&     0.04&    12.62&     0.02&    12.68&     0.03&    12.98&     0.06&    -3.39&III\\
       5&3:44:08.04&32:06:56.49&    11.61&     0.03&    11.59&     0.01&    11.61&     0.03&    11.03&     0.08&    -2.21&III\\
       6&3:44:05.67&32:10:44.97&    14.19&     0.09&    14.33&     0.04&    14.15&     0.06&    13.27&     0.13&    -1.76&II\\
       7&3:44:10.21&32:07:34.59&    12.42&     0.04&    12.32&     0.01&    12.10&     0.03&    11.83&     0.08&    -2.14&III\\
       8&3:44:11.19&32:08:16.42&    11.44&     0.03&    11.21&     0.01&    11.15&     0.01&    11.25&     0.05&    -2.64&III\\
       9&3:44:09.98&32:09:41.83&    12.68&     0.04&    12.85&     0.02&    12.84&     0.04&    12.35&     0.07&    -2.45&III\\
      10&3:44:16.53&32:05:32.97&    11.11&     0.02&    11.10&     0.01&    10.94&     0.02&    11.05&     0.03&    -2.72&III\\
      11&3:44:13.26&32:09:07.62&    14.61&     0.11&    14.37&     0.04&    14.49&     0.08&    13.40&     0.20&    -1.56&II\\
      12&3:44:17.76&32:04:47.62&    11.41&     0.03&    11.28&     0.01&    11.21&     0.02&    11.26&     0.04&    -2.67&III\\
      13&3:44:12.75&32:10:55.31&    12.91&     0.05&    12.99&     0.02&    12.96&     0.05&    12.79&     0.16&    -2.69&III\\
      14&3:44:15.56&32:09:22.01&    12.60&     0.04&    12.69&     0.02&    12.65&     0.04&    12.88&     0.13&    -3.12&III\\
      15&3:44:18.24&32:07:32.66&    11.91&     0.03&    11.95&     0.01&    11.82&     0.02&    11.37&     0.03&    -2.21&III\\
      16&3:44:21.24&32:05:02.48&    11.11&     0.02&    10.97&     0.01&    11.04&     0.03&    11.43&     0.13&    -3.23&III\\
      17&3:44:20.00&32:06:45.54&    11.69&     0.03&    11.81&     0.01&    11.91&     0.03&    12.57&     0.11&    -3.83&III\\
      18&3:44:21.68&32:06:24.91&    11.18&     0.02&    11.01&     0.01&    11.00&     0.03&    10.78&     0.08&    -2.40&III\\
      19&3:44:18.84&32:11:33.68&    14.12&     0.09&    14.21&     0.04&    13.86&     0.12&    12.13&     0.11&    -0.54&II\\
      20&3:44:23.65&32:07:11.74&    12.74&     0.05&    12.89&     0.02&    12.85&     0.04&    12.59&     0.16&    -2.64&III\\
      21&3:44:23.57&32:09:34.06&    11.80&     0.03&    11.56&     0.01&    11.39&     0.02&    10.98&     0.03&    -1.92&III\\
      22&3:44:21.18&32:12:36.58&    11.67&     0.03&    11.46&     0.01&    11.32&     0.02&    10.94&     0.04&    -2.01&III\\
      23&3:44:21.72&32:12:31.32&    11.71&     0.03&    11.44&     0.01&    11.56&     0.02&    11.87&     0.08&    -3.08&III\\
      24&3:44:27.31&32:07:17.64&    12.69&     0.04&    12.71&     0.02&    12.62&     0.07&    11.86&     0.16&    -1.89&III\\
      25&3:44:22.95&32:11:57.76&    11.33&     0.03&    11.04&     0.01&    11.12&     0.02&    11.28&     0.06&    -2.83&III\\
      26&3:44:25.71&32:09:06.07&    12.45&     0.04&    12.68&     0.02&    12.46&     0.06&    12.07&     0.16&    -2.34&III\\
      27&3:44:23.74&32:11:56.11&    12.79&     0.05&    12.85&     0.02&    13.11&     0.04&    12.16&     0.04&    -2.21&III\\
      28&3:44:29.67&32:05:52.36&    11.83&     0.03&    11.94&     0.01&    11.78&     0.04&    11.49&     0.08&    -2.41&III\\
      29&3:44:29.11&32:07:51.07&    11.69&     0.03&    11.60&     0.01&    11.68&     0.03&    12.02&     0.18&    -3.23&III\\
      30&3:44:30.48&32:06:29.34&    11.32&     0.03&    11.22&     0.01&    11.22&     0.04&    11.01&     0.12&    -2.50&III\\


\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{singlespace}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you turned your code into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that illustrates the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: You've already got the answer but you don't need any of those `\multicolumn{1}{c}` or `\multicolumn{1}{p{0.75in}}` commands they are just complicating the source for no reason as they are just replacing the column specification by the same thing in each case.

Answer (score 2):

In the header for subsequent pages you are using a long text that spans only the first 3 columns:

```
\multicolumn{3}{c}
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
```

This text is the culprit of the unwanted behavior.

Let it span the whole table and use `l` as a specifier:

```
\multicolumn{13}{l}
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
```

MWE (I've also removed all the unneeded `\multicolumn`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{singlespace}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{cp{0.75in}p{0.75in}cccccccccc}
\caption[Photometry Source List]{Photometry for all Sources found in PID 36} \\

%This is the header for the first page of the table...
 \hline
   \textbf{\#} & \textbf{RA} & \textbf{DEC} & \textbf{$m_{3.6}$} & \textbf{$\sigma_{3.6}$} &
   \textbf{$m_{4.5}$} & \textbf{$\sigma_{4.5}$} & \textbf{$m_{5.8}$} & \textbf{$\sigma_{5.8}$} &
   \textbf{$m_{8.0}$} & \textbf{$\sigma_{8.0}$} & \textbf{$\alpha_{IRAC}$} & \textbf{Class} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

%This is the header for the remaining page(s) of the table...
\multicolumn{13}{l}
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
 \hline
   \textbf{\#} & \textbf{RA} & \textbf{DEC} & \textbf{$m_{3.6}$} & \textbf{$\sigma_{3.6}$} &
   \textbf{$m_{4.5}$} & \textbf{$\sigma_{4.5}$} & \textbf{$m_{5.8}$} & \textbf{$\sigma_{5.8}$} &
   \textbf{$m_{8.0}$} & \textbf{$\sigma_{8.0}$} & \textbf{$\alpha_{IRAC}$} & \textbf{Class} \\ \hline
\endhead

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

     1&3:44:07.70&32:05:05.58&    11.77&     0.04&    11.95&     0.01&    13.01&     0.10&    11.22&     0.05&    -2.50&III\\
       2&3:44:06.16&32:07:07.08&    11.45&     0.03&    11.47&     0.01&    11.41&     0.03&    11.32&     0.05&    -2.68&III\\
       3&3:44:05.31&32:08:02.97&    12.46&     0.04&    12.62&     0.02&    12.65&     0.03&    12.18&     0.20&    -2.52&III\\
       4&3:44:04.24&32:09:38.55&    12.48&     0.04&    12.62&     0.02&    12.68&     0.03&    12.98&     0.06&    -3.39&III\\
       5&3:44:08.04&32:06:56.49&    11.61&     0.03&    11.59&     0.01&    11.61&     0.03&    11.03&     0.08&    -2.21&III\\
       6&3:44:05.67&32:10:44.97&    14.19&     0.09&    14.33&     0.04&    14.15&     0.06&    13.27&     0.13&    -1.76&II\\
       7&3:44:10.21&32:07:34.59&    12.42&     0.04&    12.32&     0.01&    12.10&     0.03&    11.83&     0.08&    -2.14&III\\
       8&3:44:11.19&32:08:16.42&    11.44&     0.03&    11.21&     0.01&    11.15&     0.01&    11.25&     0.05&    -2.64&III\\
       9&3:44:09.98&32:09:41.83&    12.68&     0.04&    12.85&     0.02&    12.84&     0.04&    12.35&     0.07&    -2.45&III\\
      10&3:44:16.53&32:05:32.97&    11.11&     0.02&    11.10&     0.01&    10.94&     0.02&    11.05&     0.03&    -2.72&III\\
      11&3:44:13.26&32:09:07.62&    14.61&     0.11&    14.37&     0.04&    14.49&     0.08&    13.40&     0.20&    -1.56&II\\
      12&3:44:17.76&32:04:47.62&    11.41&     0.03&    11.28&     0.01&    11.21&     0.02&    11.26&     0.04&    -2.67&III\\
      13&3:44:12.75&32:10:55.31&    12.91&     0.05&    12.99&     0.02&    12.96&     0.05&    12.79&     0.16&    -2.69&III\\
      14&3:44:15.56&32:09:22.01&    12.60&     0.04&    12.69&     0.02&    12.65&     0.04&    12.88&     0.13&    -3.12&III\\
      15&3:44:18.24&32:07:32.66&    11.91&     0.03&    11.95&     0.01&    11.82&     0.02&    11.37&     0.03&    -2.21&III\\
      16&3:44:21.24&32:05:02.48&    11.11&     0.02&    10.97&     0.01&    11.04&     0.03&    11.43&     0.13&    -3.23&III\\
      17&3:44:20.00&32:06:45.54&    11.69&     0.03&    11.81&     0.01&    11.91&     0.03&    12.57&     0.11&    -3.83&III\\
      18&3:44:21.68&32:06:24.91&    11.18&     0.02&    11.01&     0.01&    11.00&     0.03&    10.78&     0.08&    -2.40&III\\
      19&3:44:18.84&32:11:33.68&    14.12&     0.09&    14.21&     0.04&    13.86&     0.12&    12.13&     0.11&    -0.54&II\\
      20&3:44:23.65&32:07:11.74&    12.74&     0.05&    12.89&     0.02&    12.85&     0.04&    12.59&     0.16&    -2.64&III\\
      21&3:44:23.57&32:09:34.06&    11.80&     0.03&    11.56&     0.01&    11.39&     0.02&    10.98&     0.03&    -1.92&III\\
      22&3:44:21.18&32:12:36.58&    11.67&     0.03&    11.46&     0.01&    11.32&     0.02&    10.94&     0.04&    -2.01&III\\
      23&3:44:21.72&32:12:31.32&    11.71&     0.03&    11.44&     0.01&    11.56&     0.02&    11.87&     0.08&    -3.08&III\\
      24&3:44:27.31&32:07:17.64&    12.69&     0.04&    12.71&     0.02&    12.62&     0.07&    11.86&     0.16&    -1.89&III\\
      25&3:44:22.95&32:11:57.76&    11.33&     0.03&    11.04&     0.01&    11.12&     0.02&    11.28&     0.06&    -2.83&III\\
      26&3:44:25.71&32:09:06.07&    12.45&     0.04&    12.68&     0.02&    12.46&     0.06&    12.07&     0.16&    -2.34&III\\
      27&3:44:23.74&32:11:56.11&    12.79&     0.05&    12.85&     0.02&    13.11&     0.04&    12.16&     0.04&    -2.21&III\\
      28&3:44:29.67&32:05:52.36&    11.83&     0.03&    11.94&     0.01&    11.78&     0.04&    11.49&     0.08&    -2.41&III\\
      29&3:44:29.11&32:07:51.07&    11.69&     0.03&    11.60&     0.01&    11.68&     0.03&    12.02&     0.18&    -3.23&III\\
      30&3:44:30.48&32:06:29.34&    11.32&     0.03&    11.22&     0.01&    11.22&     0.04&    11.01&     0.12&    -2.50&III\\


\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]